# Can someone explain me the role of MOSFET in this circuit ? Are these MOSFET working as a switch here?

Tags: pic, dac

This Image is taken from the PIC16(L)F15356/75/76/85/86 MCU datasheet
[image]

[datasheet-](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC16LF15356-75-76-85-86-Data%20Sheet-40001866B.pdf) go to page number 286 for more details

Comment: Well, why could the pins driving them be called (output)enable?

Comment: Or DAC Enable on the left side

Comment: @PlasmaHH i think it's DAC_EN. There is no (output)enable i guess !

Comment: @Gahlot: In the image I see there is a pin labeled DACxOE1

Comment: @PlasmaHH oh yes. Datasheet does not give much info about these as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is answered on page 28.
[image]

Because they are enable bits, yes, they are being used as switches, turning the inputs/outputs on or off.

Comment: Thanx @MCG for confirming this.